# Makefile using wildcard and the stem for prerequisites

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

So I have a Makefile:

```
broken-%: $(wildcard src/%/*)
    @echo $*
    @echo $^

working-%: src/a/*
    @echo $*
    @echo $^
```

`$*` is `%` (the stem) and `$^` is prerequisites

And the directory structure is

```
│   Makefile
│
└───src
    └───a
            main.java
```

Using the Makefile:

```
> make broken-a
a

> make working-a
a
src/a/main.java
>
```

Both of these should have the same outputs but they don't.

For some reason `$(wildcard src/%/*)` with `%` set to `a` is returning nothing. It might be because wildcards in prerequisites are evaluated automatically so `src/%/*` is evaluated before the `wildcard` function is called?

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: At the time I'm writing this, the question and the accepted answer both have 4 up-votes. Great question, and a great answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Patterns aren't expanded until the rule is actually applied during the second phase, so when the file is first parsed by make you're calling `wildcard` with the literal string `src/%/*`.

[Secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) can be used to work around this

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
broken-%: $$(wildcard src/%/*)
    @echo $*
    @echo $^
```